# Node.js Express.js: mock request object for unit-test purpose

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, express

I have a method that check if request query string has some params:

```
checkMandatoryQueryParams (mandatoryQueryParams: String[],  req: Request): void {
    let result = true;
    mandatoryQueryParams.forEach((element, idx) => {
        if (!req.query.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

in unit-testing i need to mock the request for test it, eg:

```
describe('Utils', () => {

    it('checkMandatoryQueryParams', () => {
        const req: Request = new Request(); // pseudo-code
        req.query = "?foo=test&bar=test";   // pseudo-code
        expect( checkMandatoryQueryParams(['foo', 'bar'], req) ).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

how can i mock the express request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

Create your own mock object:

```
describe('Utils', () => {
    /**
     * Mocked Express Request object
     */
    let mockedReq;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockedReq = {
            query: {}
        };
    })

    it('checkMandatoryQueryParams', () => {
        const req = mockedReq;
        req.query = "?foo=test&bar=test";   // pseudo-code
        expect(checkMandatoryQueryParams(['foo', 'bar'], req) ).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

Use [manual mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html), similar to above:

```
describe('Utils', () => {
    /**
     * Mocked Express Request object
     */
    let mockedReq;

    beforeAll(() => {
        mockedReq = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            const req = {
                // Implementation
            };
            return req;
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => mockedReq.mockReset())

    it('checkMandatoryQueryParams', () => {
        const req = mockedReq;
        req.query = "?foo=test&bar=test";   // pseudo-code
        expect(checkMandatoryQueryParams(['foo', 'bar'], req) ).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```